# Mystery "Menu Extra"

Tags: menu-bar

Can anyone identify this menulet please? I can't drag it off the menu like others and I can't see it in any of the locations that a google search has suggested like /System/Library/PreferencePanes/.
[image]

It doesn't appear for other users on this machine.

Thanks

Comment: I also tried using Accessibility Inspector from Xcode, but it revealed nothing when cursor over mystery icon.

Comment: For me it looks like none of the os ones so it must be from an Application - On most of the Menu Extras from Applications you will get a Pane if you click on the sometimes you need to ctrl-click/right-click to get the Pane - Most of the time you will see a option to quit it and somewhere the name of the Application or at least a info/help option.

Comment: Well that's odd - I was all set to try these great looking tools only to find that the bloody icon has now gone. Thanks for taking the time to help, and if I ever do discover what it was I'll post right back here! N.

Answer (score 1):

### opensnoop

You can also use [`opensnoop`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/opensnoop.1m.html) to get more info on the icon. `opensnoop` is a Terminal app, it is pre-installed on your mac. When run with no options, `opensnoop` just prints all the files that are accesed on your computer in real-time

1. open Terminal.
2. type `sudo opensnoop`, your console will fillup fast.
3. click the icon.
4. look at the console to see which PID or which program get triggerd when clicking on the icon.

Answer (score 0):

Never seen that icon, but there are many questions on how to guess the icon on the site.

Here's how I would track it down where in your case, it's isolated to one specific user account.

1. Log out all users
2. Log in as a new user (without the icon) and dump the process table to /tmp `
3. Repeat for the other user
4. Compare the two files to see what is different.

I use Kaleidoscope/ksdiff, buy you can diff the files using other tools if you prefer:

```
ps -u `id -u` | cut -c 32- | sort | uniq > /tmp/user_ps_cleaned_`id -u`
```

So, if your user ids were 501 and 502, you could:

```
diff /tmp/user_ps_cleaned_*
```

Comment: This answer reminds me of an app that returns the PID of each GUI item the mouse hover over. Unfortunately, forgot the name...

Comment: @CousinCocaine That would be an awesome extension. I wonder if it calls some sort of responder chain to work backwards from anything that expects a click?

Comment: the app is called `xprop`, but is only available on Linux.

Comment: `opensnoop` does a quite similar job on OS X.